# mechanism of 'int(random()*10)'

Tags: python, random

In python we can use int(random()*10) to import random interger, then mechanism of this is round the decimal? I wonder this because if what I think is happen, probability of 0 and 1 should be different,,

Comment: In any case, you should use `random.randint(a, b)` if you want a random integer in the interval `[a, b]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the docs, [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) truncates floating point numbers towards zero, it does not round them. Essentially, it just chops the decimal part off. So, `int(9.999)` returns `9`, not `10`.